# Single out tags in an xml document?

Tags: python, xml, gdata

I have what I believe to be a fairly simple issue.

I've retrieved a file from gdata, this file: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments

I'm attempting to single out the tex t between the

```
"< author >HERE< /author >"
```

tags so i'll be left with an output containing only usernames. Is python even the best way to go about this or should I use another language? I've been googling since 8:00am (4hrs) and i've yet to find anything for such a seemingly easy task.

Best regards,
- Mitch Powell

Comment: Thanks for editing the post cfreak, i'm a tad new!

Comment: No problem.  Welcome to Stackoverflow. The other thing you can do is add the code you've tried so far. To make it look like I made your XML just highlight it and hit the little `{}` button (or put it backticks around it).

Comment: you can use a tool  called beautifulsoup in python . that will serve all your html parsing needs. I would not recommend anything other than python :)

Comment: He has an xml file, not html.

Comment: @FrancisAvila - BeautifulSoup supports XML

Comment: Yeah, but so does ElementTree, which is in the standard library already.

Comment: karthikr, francis.. Thank-you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an atom feed there, so I'd use [`feedparser`](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) to handle that:

```
import feedparser

result = feedparser.parse('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments')
for entry in result.entries:
    print entry.author
```

This prints:

```
FreebieFM
micromicros
FreebieFM
Sarah Grimstone
FreebieFM
# etc.
```

Feedparser is an external library, but easily installed. If you have to use only the standard library, you could use the [`ElementTree` API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), but to parse the Atom feed you need to include HTML entities in the parser, and you'll have to deal with namespaces (not `ElementTree`'s strong point):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = urlopen('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/Ej4_G-E1cAM/comments')
tree = ElementTree.parse(response)

nsmap = {'a': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
for author in tree.findall('.//a:author/a:name', namespaces=nsmap):
    print author.text
```

The `nsmap` dictionary lets `ElementTree` translate the `a:` prefix to the correct namespace for those elements.

Comment: worth mentioning that feedparser is not available by default